# How to access methods in subclasses from main method? (Java)

Tags: java

I am learning about superclasses and subclasses. 
I have to create a superclass (Campsite) and then
two subclasses(FrontCountry and BackCountry), one of which has two additional subclasses(Serviced and Unserviced).
Not bad so far, I can do all of that.
But i'm asked this question at the very end.

*In CampTester, write another static Java method called statistics which takes, as its parameter, an array of Campsite objects and determines and outputs the following:
the attribute values for each object
the total number of Front Country sites in Terra Nova National Park, Newfoundland and Labrador
the total number of serviced sites (with 30 amp service) in Newman Sound, Terra Nova National Park, Newfoundland and Labrador
the locations of all Back Country sites in Gros Morne National Park, Newfoundland and Labrador
a list, by site number, of all the unserviced sites in Malady Head, Terra Nova National Park, Newfoundland and Labrador

I'm trying to use an enhanced for loop to print the attributes for each object in an array that i've created. simple enough. The problem lies within the fact that I cannot access the methods that can retrieve the information from the subclasses that I need to tally and present.(methods like getLocation, getAmpService, get Province)

IN ESSENCE:

Is it possible to access methods defined in a subclass from outside of that subclass (higher in the hierarchy)?

Comment: Can you show your classes? I'm guessing that you're trying to call non-static methods from main, which won't work because main is static.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO.  A few suggestions - read the help section, especially [mcve].  Sadly, nobody is probably going to read your lengthy assignments, so try to whittle the problem down to the smallest possible example.

Comment: The assignment says the statistics method should be static.  If its not static you cannot call it from main.  public static void statistics(Campsite[] camps) {...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your issue correctly, it seems you didn't do the casting when you access the methods in subclass.

Assume that getLocation, getAmpService methods are only existing in FrontCountry, but not in superclass Campsite. Before you want to access these methods, you need to cast the object into FrontCountry.

```
if (campsite instanceof FrontCountry) {
     FrontCountry frontCountry = (FrontCountry)campsite;
     frontCountry.getLocation();
     frontCountry.getAmpService();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was it!

Answer (score 1):

The class variable location should be defined inside the Campsite class and it should be protected. Protected class variables are inherited. The campsite class should also have public getLocation() and setLocation() methods. The sub classes will inherit location, getLocation() and setLocation(). Any instance of Campsite (including subclass instances) will have the camp.getLocation() method.

Comment: The problem with this is location is an attribute for BackCountry, not Campsite.

Comment: try using  if( camp instanceof BackCountry ){ ((BackCountry) cammp).getLocation()}

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier to answer with the code you have so far, but basically if your FrontCountry class extends your Campsite class, and you have an array of campsites, you can do things like this to access the FrontCountry methods:

```
if (campSiteArray[0] instanceof FrontCountry){
  ((FrontCountry)campSiteArray[0]).frontCountryMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

JLaudio's answer is definitely correct. I'd also like to add that superclasses cannot access subclass methods (as your shortened question might be suggesting). The reason for this is that the class structure allows subclasses to be *more specialized* than their parents. So a method that is defined specifically in a subclass (FrontCountry or BackCountry) would not be available for a Campsite object to call.